# Creating a chocolatey package using the quick start guide fails the UTF-8 test even when using a UTF-8 supported editor

Tags: chocolatey

When running the `warmup chocolatey PackageName` command in the [Quick start guide](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CreatePackagesQuickStart) the generated nuspec file gets the omega character replaced with '???' (see below) even though I open it in an editor supporting UTF-8 (e.g. Sublime). Can I safely ignore this?
*Do not remove this test for UTF-8: if ??? doesn?t appear as greek uppercase omega letter enclosed in quotation marks, you should use an editor that supports UTF-8, not this one.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of `warmup`, which does not parse UTF-8 encoded files (without BOM) correctly.

You can safely ignore this as long as your `__CHOCO_PKG_MAINTAINER_REPO__` and `__CHOCO_PKG_MAINTAINER_NAME__` variables don’t contain non-ASCII characters, which is unlikely anyway.

But of course this is something that needs to be fixed because it creates confusion. I opened an issue for it: https://github.com/chucknorris/warmup/issues/21